# Validating Date Time Picker in flutter. (From Date selection date to To Date selection)

Tags: flutter, validation, datepicker

> I want to validating from date selection date to To date selction
> date. I selected 17th July 2022 in FromDate and ToDate selection time
> only show 4 days(17,18,19,20) how i show only 7 past dates in ToDate
> Picker in flutt[image]er.

[image]

> DateTime fromDate = DateTime.now();
> TimeOfDay fromTime = TimeOfDay.now();
> String selectedFromDateTime;
> String selectedToDateTime;
> DateTime toDate = DateTime.now();
> TimeOfDay toTime = TimeOfDay.now();

```
Future<void> _showFromDateTimePicker() async {
    final DateTime datePicked = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: fromDate,
        firstDate: DateTime(1900),
        lastDate: DateTime.now(),builder: (context, child) {
      return Theme(
        data: ThemeData(
          splashColor: AppTheme.card_bg,
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
              primary: AppTheme.card_bg,
              onSecondary: Colors.black,
              onPrimary: Colors.white,
              surface: Colors.black,
              onSurface: Colors.black,
              secondary: Colors.black),
          dialogBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
        ),
        child: child ?? Text(""),
      );
    },);

    if (datePicked != null) {
      final hour = fromTime.hour.toString().padLeft(2, "0");
      final minute = fromTime.minute.toString().padLeft(2, "0");
      final TimeOfDay timePicked =
          await showTimePicker(context: context, initialTime: fromTime,builder: (context, child) {
            return Theme(
              data: ThemeData(
                splashColor: AppTheme.card_bg,
                colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
                    primary: AppTheme.card_bg,
                    onSecondary: Colors.black,
                    onPrimary: Colors.white,
                    surface: Colors.white,
                    onSurface: Colors.black,
                    secondary: Colors.black),
                dialogBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
              ),
              child: child ?? Text(""),
            );
          },);
      if (timePicked != null) {
        setState(() {
          selectedFromDateTime =
              "${DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(datePicked)} $hour:$minute" +
                  ":00";
        });
      }
    }
  }

  Future<void> _showToDateTimePicker() async {
    final DateTime datePicked = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: toDate,
      firstDate: DateTime.now(),
      lastDate: DateTime.now(),
      builder: (context, child) {
        return Theme(
          data: ThemeData(
            splashColor: AppTheme.card_bg,
            colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
                primary: AppTheme.card_bg,
                onSecondary: Colors.black,
                onPrimary: Colors.white,
                surface: Colors.black,
                onSurface: Colors.black,
                secondary: Colors.black),
            dialogBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
          ),
          child: child ?? Text(""),
        );
      },
    );

    if (datePicked != null) {
      final hour = toTime.hour.toString().padLeft(2, "0");
      final minute = toTime.minute.toString().padLeft(2, "0");
      final TimeOfDay timePicked = await showTimePicker(
        context: context,
        initialTime: toTime,
        builder: (context, child) {
          return Theme(
            data: ThemeData(
              splashColor: AppTheme.card_bg,
              colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
                  primary: AppTheme.card_bg,
                  onSecondary: Colors.black,
                  onPrimary: Colors.white,
                  surface: Colors.white,
                  onSurface: Colors.black,
                  secondary: Colors.black),
              dialogBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
            ),
            child: child ?? Text(""),
          );
        },
      );
      if (timePicked != null) {
        setState(() {
          selectedToDateTime =
              "${DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(datePicked)} $hour:$minute" +
                  ":00";
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hello Nitish can you tell me how many days you want to be selected in to_date ?

Comment: This is first condition(I SELECT IN FORM DATE PICKER IN DATE 17th JULY then in TODATEPICKER IN SHOW ONLY 17,18,19,20 th JULY DATE

Comment: this is second condition(i select  current date in from date like 20th july when todate in only show 20th july)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite easy to do, you just need to subtract 7 days from today.

```dart
  final sevenDaysBeforeToday =DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 7));
```

and change `firstDate` to `sevenDaysBeforeToday` of `showDatePicker`

```dart
    firstDate: sevenDaysBeforeToday,
```

Comment: Usman Karim your answer is good but i want aspect the answer like (I SELECT IN FORM DATE PICKER IN DATE 17th JULY then in TODATEPICKER IN SHOW ONLY 17,18,19,20 th JULY DATE  )

Comment: Can you please elaborate more precisely on what are you trying to say?

Comment: This is first condition(I SELECT IN FORM DATE PICKER IN DATE 17th JULY then in TODATEPICKER IN SHOW ONLY 17,18,19,20 th JULY DATE

Comment: this is second condition(i select current date in from date like 20th july when todate in only show 20th july)

Comment: Maybe you should try to use `showDateRangePicker` https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDateRangePicker.html